# Passing callbacks into JS object constructor with embind in C++

Tags: javascript, c++, webassembly, emscripten

I am looking for a way to instantiate and use [VideoDecoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VideoDecoder) in C++ code of webassembly app. Here is an [example](https://github.com/w3c/webcodecs/tree/main/samples/video-decode-display) of the setup:

```
const decoder = new VideoDecoder({
output(frame)
{
    renderFrame(frame);
},
error(e)
{
     setStatus("decode", e);
}});
```

VideoDecoder class constructor has the following signature:

```
const videoDecoder = new VideoDecoder({
        output: processVideo,
        error: onEncoderError,
});
```

In cpp I initiate `VideoDecoder` like this:

```
static void OnVideoFrame(emscripten::val frame)
{
}

static void OnError(emscripten::val error)
{
}
struct DecodeSettings_t
{
    void (*output)(emscripten::val);
    void (*error)(emscripten::val);
};

void VideoManager::Init(){
  emscripten::val VideoDecoder = emscripten::val::global("VideoDecoder");
  DecodeSettings_t set;
  set.output = &OnError;
  set.error = &OnVideoFrame;  
  videoDecoderInst = VideoDecoder.new_(set);
}
```

When launching the app I am getting the following error:

> {name: 'BindingError', message: 'parameter 0 has unknown type
> N2sn16DecodeSettings_tE', stack: 'BindingError: parameter 0 has
> unknown type ..}

Looks like DecodeSettings_t  struct is unrecognized, which kind of makes sense. So I tried to simulate a dynamic JS object creation in C++ and passing it into the constructor:

```
emscripten::val obj = emscripten::val::object();
obj.set("output", &OnVideoFrame);
obj.set("error", &OnError);
videoDecoderInst = VideoDecoder.new_(obj);
```

Now I am getting this error on web app startup:

> RuntimeError: Aborted(LinkError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import
> #116 module="env" function="_emval_new_object" error: function import requires a callable)

What am I missing here?